Calling a Flask macro dynamically using a variable name
I have a big if-elif structure that calls specific macros based on the names of dynamically called variables, like this:
{% macro select_macro() %}
do stuff
{%- if context.key == 'value1' %}
{{ macro_value1 }}
{%- elif context.key == 'value2' %}
{{ macro_value2 }}
{%- elif context.key == 'value3' %}
{{ macro_value3 }}
{% endif %}
do more stuff
{% endmacro %}

To clarify, there's already a separate child_macros.html file with:
{% macro macro_value1() %}
do stuff when value1
{% endmacro %}

{% macro macro_value2() %}
do stuff when value2
{% endmacro %}

{% macro macro_value3() %}
do stuff when value3
{% endmacro %}

To have a more "pythonic" code that calls the needed child macros dynamically, I've tried using @pass_context using the example shown in the second related question below (which still uses deprecated @contextfilter), but I'm getting errors stating that the value object is not bound to a Session. I have an app factory structure, and the @pass_context function was defined in the decorators.py. The Flask documentation on @pass_context is very economical, to say the least. Any advice or a functioning example will be greatly appreciated.
Related questions:

"eval" statement in Jinja2 template
How can I indirectly call a macro in a Jinja2 template?

